# If conditions for strings

Tags: conditionals

I use a Python Code to replace `{{ skill0 }}` with a input of the user.
In case the user does not type anything. I would like to ignore this entire part `\cvtag{ {{ skill0 }} }`.
Basically I am looking for a way to check if `{{ skill0 }}` contains any text.

The idea would look like this:

```
\if {{ skill0 }}
    \cvtag{ {{ skill0 }} }
```

This below is the `\cvtag` command:

```
\newcommand{\cvtag}[1]{%%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}
```

and finally the code:

```
\cvtag{ {{ skill0 }} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, only the sequence `\cvtag{ {{ skill0 }} }` (including the spaces) should return nothing, while in any other case you want to return the `\cvtag` with the value provided by the argument.

This, you can do, for example, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cvtag}{ m }{%
    \str_if_eq:noTF { #1 } { \tl_to_str:n {~{{~skill0~}}~} } {} {
        \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base, draw=blue!30, rounded~corners, inner~xsep=1ex, inner~ysep=0.75ex, text~height=1.5ex, text~depth=.25ex]{#1};
    }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X\cvtag{skill0}X

X\cvtag{{{skill0}}}X

X\cvtag{ {{ skill0 }} }X

X\cvtag{something else}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also test whether the argument is blank (that is, only consisting of spaces or nothing) like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cvtag}{ m }{%
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } {} {
        \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base, draw=blue!30, rounded~corners, inner~xsep=1ex, inner~ysep=0.75ex, text~height=1.5ex, text~depth=.25ex]{#1};
    }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X\cvtag{skill0}X

X\cvtag{ {{ skill0 }} }X

X\cvtag{ }X

X\cvtag{something else}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note: Within the expl3 environment, you need to use `~` everywhere you want to input a space. In these examples, it is needed inside the string comparison and for the Ti*k*Z options.

Comment: hmm not really. Sorry for not formulating my question correctly.
The part `{{ skill0 }}` is going to be replaced by any input of the user. However, if the user does not fill out the form, the entire `\cvtag{ }` should not be printed.

Comment: @GCMeccariello Okay, sorry, then I misread your question. See my edit.